# In highcharts how to format the number of percentage

Tags: highcharts, string-formatting

Hi I want to show 7% instead of 7.0000000001% when I use `point.percentage`

I do not find the `percentageDecimals` in the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip) or any thing that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try point.percentage.toFixed(0);